# Unable to view the overview of activated APIs in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am the owner of a project that has the Places API enabled (using an organizational account). However, when I try to access https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/places-backend.googleapis.com/overview?... , I am unable to view the page and am redirected to the registration for the Google Maps Platform free trial.

I have a Billing Account associated with it.
Other owners with the same permissions can view this page.

I am only eligible for billing support as I am on the Basic Plan.

What could be the possible reasons why I alone cannot display the corresponding page? What should I do?

Despite clearing my browsing history and using a private browser, I still couldn't access the relevant page.